# Is there a shadow child combinator in CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors, shadow-dom

Google Chrome supports the shadow descendant combinator `/deep/` which goes through shadow nodes.

```
body div {...} // doesn't select descendant divs inside shadow nodes
body /deep/ div {...} // selects all descendant divs, shadow or not
```

Is there an equivalent shadow combinator for children nodes (direct descendants)?

Comment: What even is `/deep/`? I don't see it anywhere in [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-scoping/).

Comment: @TylerH, custom Chrome additions (yet another).

Comment: @TylerH: Shadow-piercing descendant combinator. It's been replaced with `>>>`, not unlike `>>` in selectors-4. You can find a reference to `/deep/` (and a passing mention of `>>`) in [this WD](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-css-scoping-1-20140403/#deep-combinator).

Comment: @BoltClock, that makes much more sense, `>`, `>>` and `>>>`, child, descendant and super-descendant. Much better syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't such a combinator. To select elements that are top-level in their shadow trees, use the child combinator in conjunction with the [`::shadow` pseudo-element](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-scoping/#shadow-pseudoelement):

```
::shadow > div
```

This matches any `div` that is a top-level element in any shadow tree (represented by `::shadow`, or more explicitly, `*::shadow`).

Comment: I believe they now have a "Shadow-Piercing descendant combinator." It's ">>>"

Comment: @Gabe Rogan: Yeah, I mentioned the >>> combinator in the comments above, but it's not the answer. The asker wants to select only the top level shadow tree element, which requires the use of a child combinator - the >>> combinator will match elements at any level, much like the regular descendant combinator.

Comment: Unfortunately `::shadow` has been removed. Can you update your answer? https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/remove-shadow-piercing

Comment: @connexo: I don't really know what to change my answer to, since there doesn't appear to be any replacement for it. What do you suggest?